# SDL_Texture seems to changing to NULL during runtime, causing EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: c++, ios, sdl-2

I'm writing a game mainly in C++ (and some ObjC) with SDL2 for iOS. I have managed to get a cyan background, but when I try to create image rendering code, it gives me an EXC_BAD_ACCESS on `m_Texture` (`SDL_Texture*`). I am mainly testing my code using the iOS Simulator.

I have tried to add null checks to `m_Texture`, reading SDL_GetError (even during main loop) all to no luck.

The problematic crashing code is in `Image::OnUpdate`. I also added a comment to explain the check done there. Xcode states that `m_Texure` is `NULL`

Image.cpp:

```
#include "Image.hpp"

#include "../Utility/File.hpp"
#include "../Utility/Exception.hpp"
#include "../Rendering/Renderer.hpp"

#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "../External/stb_image.h"

#include "../External/SDL2/SDL.h"

Image::Image()
    : m_Width(0), m_Height(0), m_X(0), m_Y(0)
{

}

Image::~Image()
{
    SDL_DestroyTexture(m_Texture);
}

void Image::CreateImage(const std::string path, int width, int height, int x, int y)
{
    // TODO: Set req_format into an argument using an enum variable
    int _width, _height, _bpp, req_format = STBI_rgb;

    m_Path = path;
    if(!File::Instance()->FileExists(m_Path))
    {
        throw Exception("File \"" + path + "\" does not exist.");
    }

    unsigned char* _data = stbi_load(m_Path.c_str(), &_width, &_height, &_bpp, req_format);

    int depth, pitch;
    Uint32 pixel_format;
    if (req_format == STBI_rgb)
    {
        depth = 24;

        // 3 bytes per pixel * pixels per row
        pitch = 3*_width;
        pixel_format = SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGB24;
    }
    else
    {
        // STBI_rgb_alpha (RGBA)
        depth = 32;

        // 4 bytes per pixel * pixels per row
        pitch = 4*_width;
        pixel_format = SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA32;
    }

    SDL_Surface* _surface = SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceWithFormatFrom((void*)_data, _width, _height, depth, pitch, pixel_format);
    if(_surface == NULL)
    {
        throw Exception("Cannot create surface from image " + m_Path + ":" + std::string(SDL_GetError()));
    }
    stbi_image_free(_data);

    m_Texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(Renderer::Instance()->GetRenderer(), _surface);
    if(m_Texture == NULL)
    {
        throw Exception("Cannot create texture from image " + m_Path + ":" + std::string(SDL_GetError()));
    }
    SDL_FreeSurface(_surface);

    m_X = x;
    m_Y = y;
    m_Width = width;
    m_Height = height;

    m_Rect.x = x;
    m_Rect.y = y;
    m_Rect.w = width;
    m_Rect.h = height;

    // Make sure that the texture is enabled by default.
    m_IsEnabled = true;
}

bool Image::IsEnabled()
{
    return m_IsEnabled;
}

void Image::OnUpdate()
{
    // This !m_Texture check was added as part of my debugging process. It crashes here regardless if this check is here or not.
    if(!m_Texture)
    {
        throw Exception("Texture was null during Image::OnUpdate: " + std::string(SDL_GetError()));
    }
    SDL_RenderCopy(Renderer::Instance()->GetRenderer(), m_Texture, NULL, NULL);
}

void Image::Show()
{
    m_IsEnabled = true;
}

void Image::Hide()
{
    m_IsEnabled = false;
}
```

Image.hpp:

```
#ifndef Image_hpp
#define Image_hpp

#include <string>

//#include "../Rendering/Renderer.hpp"

#include "../External/SDL2/SDL.h"

class Image
{
    std::string m_Path;
    int m_Width, m_Height;
    int m_X, m_Y;
    bool m_IsEnabled;

    SDL_Texture* m_Texture;
    SDL_Rect m_Rect;
public:
    Image();
    ~Image();

    void CreateImage(const std::string path, int width, int height, int x, int y);
    void OnUpdate();
    void Show();
    void Hide();
    bool IsEnabled();
};

#endif /* Image_hpp */
```

Here is the Xcode Logging output (mind the probably useless debug messages):

```
2019-01-16 01:48:35.901338+0000 Grass Cut[7972:822083] Unknown class GameViewController in Interface Builder file.
2019-01-16 01:48:35.919865+0000 Grass Cut[7972:822083] DEBUG: Screen Size Native: 320x568
2019-01-16 01:48:35.934069+0000 Grass Cut[7972:822083] [MC] Lazy loading NSBundle MobileCoreServices.framework
2019-01-16 01:48:35.936290+0000 Grass Cut[7972:822083] [MC] Loaded MobileCoreServices.framework
2019-01-16 01:48:35.954627+0000 Grass Cut[7972:822083] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /Users/seanny/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/736EB4BE-C093-400E-B35A-CF570DCAF48D/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2019-01-16 01:48:35.988450+0000 Grass Cut[7972:822083] DEBUG: Window created with width of 320 and height of 568.
2019-01-16 01:48:36.030234+0000 Grass Cut[7972:822083] DEBUG: Game Engine initialized, starting main loop.
2019-01-16 01:48:36.030451+0000 Grass Cut[7972:822083] WARNING: SDL Error: Setting the swap interval is not supported
2019-01-16 01:48:36.030595+0000 Grass Cut[7972:822083] DEBUG: Event OnUpdate
2019-01-16 01:48:36.047651+0000 Grass Cut[7972:822083] WARNING: EVENT: Did Enter Foreground
2019-01-16 01:48:36.048279+0000 Grass Cut[7972:822083] DEBUG: Renderer OnUpdate
(lldb)
```

Address Sanitizer Output:

```
=================================================================
==8833==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x6020000360d8 at pc 0x00010835c5c2 bp 0x7ffee78ae990 sp 0x7ffee78ae988
READ of size 8 at 0x6020000360d8 thread T0
dyld: dyld_sim cannot be loaded in a restricted process
==8833==WARNING: external symbolizer didn't start up correctly!
```

Comment: It's possible for `m_Texture` to not be `NULL` but still not be valid. If your exception is not thrown, that's probably the case. You should try running with [Address Sanitizer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/code_diagnostics/address_sanitizer/enabling_the_address_sanitizer) turned on. It  will likely point out the problem in more detail.

Comment: I enabled Address Sanitizer, but the debug info I got made no sense.

Comment: It's saying you're reading memory on the heap that you don't own or  have permission to access.  Most likely this  means you're reading past  the end of an array somewhere.  There are  other  memory debugging tools you can turn on such as MallocGuardEdges, MallocScribble, Zombies, etc. (You may have to turn off Address Sanitizer  to turn those on.) You should turn them on and see what it tells you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the issue was, after some digging around in my code, I noticed a for loop of a file I didn't post was causing the issue.

Problematic Code:

```
void Renderer::OnUpdate()
{
    ....
    for(int i = 0; i < (int)sizeof(m_Images); i++)
    {
        if(m_Images[i]->IsEnabled() == true)
        {
            m_Images[i]->OnUpdate();
        }
    }
    ....
}
```

Fixed code:

```
void Renderer::OnUpdate()
{
    ....
    for(int i = 0; i < m_Images.size(); i++)
    {
        if(m_Images[i]->IsEnabled() == true)
        {
            m_Images[i]->OnUpdate();
        }
    }
    ....
}
```